# Naming convention for Python regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, naming-conventions, naming

Is there an accepted naming convention for regular expressions in Python? Or if there's not, what are some suggestions on how to name them?

Usually I name them something like `look_for_date` or `address_re` but I've read several places that using a suffix like '_re' in a variable name isn't good.  To me it seems like the regex needs something to indicate it's a regex, since if you named it just `date` or `address`, you wouldn't be able to do stuff like this, which seems intuitive:

```
date = date_re.match(text)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compiled regular expressions are generally *constants*, so should have an `UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` name per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants). I tend to name them for what they would match; to give an example from some code I wrote recently:

```
import re

VALID_CLOSURE_PATTERN = re.compile(r'''
    ^\d{2}    # starts with two digits 0-9
    [NY]{4}$  # followed by four Y/N characters
''', re.IGNORECASE + re.VERBOSE)


class RoadClosure(object):

    def __init__(self, ..., closure_pattern):
        """Initialise the new instance."""
        if not VALID_CLOSURE_PATTERN.match(closure_pattern):
            raise ValueError('invalid closure pattern: {!r}'.format(closure_pattern))
       ...

...
```

I think this makes it pretty clear what's going on, `VALID_CLOSURE_PATTERN` communicates *"this describes what we would consider to be a valid closure pattern"* and a line like:

```
if not VALID_CLOSURE_PATTERN.match(closure_pattern):
```

describes what it's actually doing in close to plain English. So in your case, you might write:

```
date = VALID_DATE.match(text)
```

Comment: Cool, I meant to ask about the upper case thing too.  Thanks for the answer.  So these are guidelines and not carved in stone by the PEP gods?